# how to set Shutdown parameters for rabbit mq listener

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-rabbit

we are trying to shutdown all process which are all running in micro service

1. Any Consumer currently doing some work when trying to ack
   their current message
2. Any other action on the channel. I'd like to let the consumers
   finish whatever message they're processing and then close everything
   down.
3. if we stop the running process and allow the transfer of data then wait until the specified time period mentioned in shutdown hook timeout and then it gets terminated.

we have created bean like below

```
 @Bean
  public SimpleMessageListenerContainer SimpleMessageListenerContainer() {

      SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(rabbitConnectionFactory);
      container.setIdleEventInterval(60000L);
      container.setShutdownTimeout(900000); // tried 
      return container;
  }
```

with above bean tried to achieve but it did't work. we are using spring-rabbit 1.7.3.RELEASE.

log:

```
2018-02-13 13:07:11.137  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Waiting for workers to finish.
2018-02-13 13:07:11.137  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Successfully waited for workers to finish.
2018-02-13 13:07:11.137  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor        : Stopping beans in phase 2147482647
2018-02-13 13:07:11.137  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Waiting for workers to finish.
2018-02-13 13:07:11.137  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Successfully waited for workers to finish.
2018-02-13 13:07:11.137  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.i.a.i.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter      : stopped inbound.x
2018-02-13 13:07:11.138  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor        : Stopping beans in phase 1073741823
2018-02-13 13:07:11.139  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Waiting for workers to finish.
2018-02-13 13:07:11.139  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Successfully waited for workers to finish.
2018-02-13 13:07:11.139  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.i.a.i.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter      : stopped a
2018-02-13 13:07:11.140  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Waiting for workers to finish.
2018-02-13 13:07:11.140  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Successfully waited for workers to finish.
2018-02-13 13:07:11.140  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.i.a.i.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter      : stopped b
2018-02-13 13:07:11.140  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Waiting for workers to finish.
2018-02-13 13:07:11.140  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Successfully waited for workers to finish.
2018-02-13 13:07:11.140  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.i.a.i.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter      : stopped c
2018-02-13 13:07:11.140  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Waiting for workers to finish.
2018-02-13 13:07:11.140  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Successfully waited for workers to finish.
2018-02-13 13:07:11.140  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.i.a.i.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter      : stopped d
2018-02-13 13:07:11.140  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Waiting for workers to finish.
2018-02-13 13:07:11.140  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Successfully waited for workers to finish.
2018-02-13 13:07:11.140  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.i.a.i.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter      : stopped e
2018-02-13 13:07:11.140  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor        : Stopping beans in phase 0
2018-02-13 13:07:11.140  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer              : Removing {json-to-object-transformer:convertEventJSONToObject} as a subscriber to the 'eventJSONToObjectChannel' channel
2018-02-13 13:07:11.141  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.i.c.DirectChannel                    : Channel 'xxx:local:8006.eventJSONToObjectChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
2018-02-13 13:07:11.143  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer              : stopped convertEventJSONToObject
2018-02-13 13:07:11.144  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer              : Removing {bridge} as a subscriber to the 'asyncEventTypeRouterChannel' channel
2018-02-13 13:07:11.144  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.i.c.ExecutorChannel                  : Channel 'xxx:local:1234.asyncEventTypeRouterChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
2018-02-13 13:07:11.144  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer              : stopped org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0
2018-02-13 13:07:11.144  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer              : Removing {router:springIntEventRouter} as a subscriber to the 'eventTypeRouterChannel' channel
2018-02-13 13:07:11.145  INFO 13412 --- [on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.i.c.DirectChannel                    : Channel 'xxx:local:1234.eventTypeRouterChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
```

have tried with setting shutdown properties to container but still it gets  shutdown by default sec or before that ;and not with override set properties.

- Is it a better way to set for each and every inbound-channel-adapter the shutdown properties, if that's the case we have to configure for more than 100 channel
- we have tested by terminate button in STS and by ctr+c in console for **above 1 and 2 point** to achieve  but it's not waiting for mentioned shutdown time.kindly help on this.
- is there any way to determine the duration of shutdown time run.

Comment: The container will wait for the `shutdownTimeout`, so the current message in process will complete before the container is stopped.

If that's not happening, edit your question to explain exactly what you are seeing and add a DEBUG log showing the shutdown sequence.

Comment: Sry right  now am out of office.it will be help full if u have any small sample example to achieve above scenarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works exactly as you have it...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So48747564Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So48747564Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitTemplate template, SimpleMessageListenerContainer container) {
        return args -> {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String line = null;
            while (!"quit".equals(line)) {
                line = scanner.nextLine();
                template.convertAndSend("so48747564", line);
            }
            scanner.close();
            container.stop();
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(cf);
        container.setQueueNames("so48747564");
        container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(new Object() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public void handleMessage(String in) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Received: " + in);
                Thread.sleep(5_000);
                System.out.println("Listener exiting");
            }

        }));
        container.setShutdownTimeout(10_000);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new Queue("so48747564");
    }

}
```

Result:

```
foo
Received: foo
Listener exiting
quit
Received: quit
2018-02-12 13:31:23.585  INFO 14916 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer 
: Waiting for workers to finish.
Listener exiting
2018-02-12 13:31:28.589  INFO 14916 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer 
: Successfully waited for workers to finish.
```

Comment: thx for reply and sample program .correct me if am wrong by setting  setShutdownTimeout we can able to ack the message if it proccessing and it will terminate with in time of period .its more less like this concept  right Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running Shutdown Hook");
      }
    });

Comment: Right; you can add a shutdown hook and `stop()` the application context (which calls `container.stop()`). Spring Boot does that automatically for you.

Comment: updated log and some explanation kindly help on this

Comment: You must run the listener on the container thread; if you hand off the work to another thread via a `QueueChannel` or `ExecutorChannel` (or any other means), there is nothing the container can do to wait for the work to complete. You must not do that anyway, unless you don't mind losing messages. Show your __complete__ configuration.

Comment: No we are not using any QueueChannel or Executor channel. It's just xml configuration with channels, inbound,  out bound adapter and by service activator invoking class reference.is there any other way to over come this scenario by exiting configuration

Comment: Huh? `[on(9)-127.0.0.1] o.s.i.c.ExecutorChannel ... xxx:local:1234.asyncEventTypeRouterChannel`. You definitely have an async hand-off there - which is not a good idea if you don't want to lose messages. Show your configuration, please.

Comment: So where is `asyncEventTypeRouterChannel`? From your logs it is clear that the container threads were not doing any work when you stopped the context.

Comment: sry for late update am out of town, we are using executor for async purpose  updated in post ,but to how over  come this scenario by omitting above config   or there any other way to achieve this.kindly on help on this.

Comment: You must **not use an executor if you don't want to lose messages**. If you added the executor so you can handle concurrent messages, you should manage the concurrency on the listener container itself. `container.setConcurrentConsumers(5)` and then you won't lose messages and the `stop()` will be suspended until your listeners complete.

Comment: thx for reply is there any hands on sample available to understand better how  its works exceutor+container it will be great full if u provide .

Comment: What do you mean? Just remove the executor and increase the container concurrency; not sure why you need an example. If the concurrency is 5 the container will process 5 messages at a time. With an executor, there is nothing the container can do to wait until the work is complete.